# Why conv2d yields different results with different batch size

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I feed the **conv2d** with the same data but different batch size (using stack) as input:

```py
a = torch.rand(1, 512, 16, 16)  # (1, 512, 16, 16)
b = torch.cat([a, a, a], dim=0) # (3, 512, 16, 16)

a, b = a.cuda(), b.cuda()

net = nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
net = net.cuda()

ay = net(a)
by = net(b)

print('ay[0], by[0] max diff', torch.max(torch.abs(ay[0] - by[0])).item())
print('ay[0], by[0] allclose', torch.allclose(ay[0], by[0]))
```

the result is however different:

```
ay[0], by[0] diff 3.5762786865234375e-06
ay[0], by[0] allclose False
```

this problem is tested on Linux + V100 + torch1.9.0 + cu111, but so far many other configuration also seen such problem. Any clue why? Or it is just simply I misunderstand how conv2d should work?

I run into this problem when I validate my **trainset** result using batch size 1, but it is significantly different from the error I recorded from training process, so I checked for it and find that it is the conv2d layer that causes this problem. If I understand conv2d correctly, this should not be happening.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same result on the CPU with much smaller data. After further testing, at least on the CPU, I could only reproduce it with a batch size of 1 vs N. In other words, I could not reproduce it with 2 vs N. From this result, I suspect that Conv2d is optimized differently when the batch size is 1, which introduces additional rounding errors. The problem is that I could not prove this hypothesis because it is too hard to investigate pytorch's native code.

Comment: Since I have to use batch size 1 for validating and testing, the precision error for batch size 1 does matter. Although for well distributed output such precision error should not cause much difference, I still curious about how such problem still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the problem is *not* specific to **con2d** operations, but rather do to a limited floating point precision which can vary depending on the operations and architecture. This is a known issue, see e.g. this discussion on the [pytorch-forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/slightly-different-results-for-different-batch-sizes/43458).

The GPU calculations you are currently running is probably using single-precision float computations, if you set it to be double-precision the error discrepancies should be reduced:

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)
```

meaning that:

```
print('ay[0], by[0] allclose', torch.allclose(ay[0], by[0], atol=1e-6))
```

Should print:

> ay[0], by[0] allclose True

At least this is the case for me when testing also on Linux using an A100.